# Functional Specification for Common Criteria EAL 1 evaluation

Tags: documents, common-criteria

I want to write a functional specification for CC EAL1 evaluation, There is an example in CC part 3 document but it is not enough complete, Are there any template or sample of a functional specification for CC EAL 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the guidance from the German scheme, on page 83 of the following document:

http://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/ccfiles/CommonCriteriaDevelopersGuide_1_0.pdf

Comment: Please consider quoting parts of the document to improve your answer as links become outdated.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, But that is the same example in CC part 3 document... I investigate for a really working example that indicates SFR-enforcing and SFR-supporting TSFIs and also indicates relation of TSFIs to SFRs according to EAL 1 requirements, but thanks again anyway for your reply...

Comment: i had read specially this guide before... but now i have read it again and found some new points in it that helps me on my problem,